# What are the audio specs for J2ME mobile games?

Tags: mobile, audio, java-me, j2mepolish

Just curious about the general specs for audio.  Like, what audio file format?  Size/Length limitations?

I'm sure j2me is fragmented into many platforms, but ust trying to get a grasp.  After hearing all the news with Whats App, it made me realize that j2me is still important.

I am hoping to compile a helpful article regarding j2me standards and practices for mobile games

Comment: is anybody actually using a phone these days that's based on J2ME?

Comment: yes, they still account for around 45% of all phones in active use....

Answer (score 0):

The MMAPI (JSR 135) (used in MIDP1.0) and the `Player` classes of MIDP2.0 supports playback of Standard MIDI Format and Adaptable Multi-Rate Wideband (AMR) files.

Most J2ME enabled phones nowadays also support playback of MP3 and WAV files.

The typical way of doing audio for a game, is to either

- use MIDI file(s) for music and AMR files for sound effects, both playing at the same time, or
- use MIDI file(s) for both music and sound effects, where only one can play at a time.

In the beginning, phones could typically only handle 1 Player object at a time. As a result, you had to make the user select whether he wanted music or sound effects.
Later on, 2 simultaneous `Player` objects became possible, but only if they handled 2 different formats. You couldn't (and still can't) play two MIDI files at the same time.

Even today there are only very few phones that supports more than 2 simultaneous `Player` objects.

A lot of phones also supports the brilliant Mobile eXtensible Music File Format (XMF/mXMF) - but only some of them does it correctly. XMF basically consists of a MIDI file + a sound-font. Meaning, it allows you to provide your own instruments for your MIDI file. For one thing this means that your music will (finally) sound the same on all devices.
Another interesting use for this was to provide a sound-font containing multiple sound effects, and that way have something similar to the SoundPool you can have with Android.

I've done extensive testing with the XMF format, and sadly found that the XMF format is poorly supported. Only Symbian devices seems to support it well. Sony Ericsson feature phones are very buggy and limited when it comes to XMF playback (will only play XMF files containing a sound-font less than 30kb - and even then it sometimes just crashes). And other brands seems to not support it at all, so sadly I have to recommend that you avoid the format.
As a musician I was rather annoyed by that, because it could really have given the J2ME platform some awesomeness regarding audio.

There's been experiments in the past regarding playback of MODules (MOD/XM/S3M/IT files). I won't go into details, but just say that it's not the way to go. Almost no phones can handle it.

On newer J2ME enabled phones you can get away with using MP3 for music nowadays. But it does take up memory of course. So in order to support as many devices as possible, **the best practise is to use MIDI for music and AMR files for sound effects**.
You can e.g. create your music `Player` first, and then in a try/catch block load a sound effect. If it fails, it'll just be null. So you check if the sound effect object is null before starting playback.

Next comes the various tips'n'tricks for getting your audio to play on as many devices as possible.
I have written some guidelines about that here:

http://www.indiegamemusic.com/help.php?id=1

*IndieGameMusic.com also contains several MIDI files optimized for J2ME. Stripped unnecessary data, keeping polyphony down, filesize to a minimum. Some tracks even available in multiple formats, like MIDI for J2ME, XM for Android/iPhone, MP3/OGG for other, so developers can support multiple platforms, having their game contain the same track*.

Comment: Thanks! How does one create an AMR file?  What is your toolset and workflow?

Comment: There exists various WAV to AMR conversion tools, or MP3 to AMR.